# Groovy does not receive Map from python script correctly

Tags: python, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins pipeline to receive data ( Map ) from Python script 3.x

In Python :

```
return MAP ( dict() )
```

Jenkins pipeline ( groovy ) :

```
def var= bat(script: "python D:\\getData.py", returnStdout: true)
```

but var will be null

I believe that python function return data because i tried to use `print` instead of `return` in Terminal

and needed data retrieves correctly in terminal 
How to solve that problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#-bat-%20windows%20batch%20script

`bat` returns or status code or stdout as text.

There is no other way to pass data as a string.

So, you could print out your map as json, and in groovy parse it.